# Resize of UIViewController in storyboard

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I want to resize a `UIViewController` in the storyboard so I can use its `UIViewController` as a popover view.

On most sites I can read that the actions are:

- drag a `UIViewController` in the storyboard
- put a `UIView` on it
- set the attribute on freeform and resize

But in my iOS 5.1 this does not work, even with a new project with only one `UIViewController`.
What did I forget in the procedure?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We follow the following steps to achieve the same:

1. Drag a `UIViewController` (this takes a `UIView` along with it, so no need to add another `UIView` unless you need more)
2. Select `UIViewController` on StoryBoard and set size property to `Freeform`
3. Select the `UIView` and set the height and width values.

If this doesn't help,  you might want to delete the `UIView` that comes with the `UIViewController`, add a fresh `UIView` and repeat #2, and #3 above.

Comment: For those who want more detail - you set the size in the Size Inspector.

Comment: Thanks! I remembered something along those lines and when I saw "Freeform" today in a XIB (where you can actually drag...) I was "WOW. Cool". Too bad it's so cumbersome in a Storyboard, but oh well :)

Comment: This worked for me, but I found I also needed to change the "Resize View From NIB" property to false. (It's in the  View Controller's Layout Property section of the Attributes Inspector.) Otherwise the controller decided to go full screen.

Comment: Here did not work. Still the UIViewController is loaded at fullscreen and not 1024x693 as this is the size I want on the iPad.

Comment: I did exactly as you told but when I press the button to bring it forward the full view comes. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

1. Drag a UIViewController

2 .Select UIViewController on StoryBoard and set size property to Freeform

[image]

3. select UIViewController on storyboard Enable user preferred explicit size in Content size in attributes inspector

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to take off "Resize View from NIB" in IB attributes tab.