# How can I show a UIDatePicker inside a Popover on iPad using StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, ipad, uidatepicker, popover, uitextfielddelegate

I have achieved to show the datepicker inside the popover, doing it programmatically as it is shown in [UIDatePicker in UIPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover?rq=1).

But I have been trying to do it in interface Builder, I already made a View Controller named DatePickerViewController.m with a DatePicker in it and its corresponding IBoulet

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DatePickerViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *birthdayDatePicker;

@end
```

[image: DatePicker inside DatePickerViewController.m in StoryBoard]

Then I need this to be shown in a popover when the Birthday text field is being edited. so I use the following code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //Assign DatePicker to Birthday TextField
    //build our custom popover view
    DatePickerViewController* popoverContent = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] init];
    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 216);

    // dismiss existing popover
    if (self.popoverControllerBirthday)
    {
        [self.popoverControllerBirthday dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        self.popoverControllerBirthday = nil;
    }

    //create a popover controller with my DatePickerViewController in it
    UIPopoverController *popoverControllerForDate = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    //Set the delegate to self to receive the data of the Datepicker in the popover
    popoverControllerForDate.delegate = self;
    //Adjust the popover Frame to appear where I want
    CGRect myFrame =textField.frame;
    myFrame.origin.x = 260;
    myFrame.origin.y = 320;

    //Present the popover
    [popoverControllerForDate presentPopoverFromRect:myFrame 
                                          inView:self.view 
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown 
                                        animated:YES];
    self.popoverControllerBirthday = popoverControllerForDate;
    return NO; // tells the textfield not to start its own editing process (ie show the keyboard)

}
```

And I also import the custom DatePickerViewController in my current ViewController

```
#import "DatePickerViewController.h"
```

But it is not showing the datepicker inside the popover.

[image]

Does anybody know what could be happening?

Comment: Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343106/815179

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved

All I have to do is instantiate the StoryBoard Date Picker View Controller like :

```
...
DatePickerViewController* popoverContent = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] init];

popoverContent =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                         bundle:nil]
               instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DatePickerVC"];
//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
...
```

where the identifier is set in StoryBoard Attributes Inspector

[image: Where to set the View controller Identifier]

and now it is shown

[image: DatePicker from DatePickerViewController is now showed]

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. How did you get the ViewController to be the same size as the DatePicker?  I've got a massive iPad sized VC with a DatePicker at the bottom. I have the same hierarchy as you: VC > View > Picker but its massive.  And, like you, it's not showing up.

Comment: I found out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728952/resize-of-uiviewcontroller-in-storyboard).  You need resize things in the Size Inspector.

Comment: @DavidCespedes how do you recognize  when user chooses his date ?

Comment: Use the onValueChange event (I think that's how is called) of the Datepicker

Answer (score 13):

You might want to avoid all the work in the storyboard by creating the ViewController and the DatePicker programmatically:

```
//build our custom popover view
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
UIDatePicker *pView=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

self.datePicker = pView;
[v addSubview:self.datePicker];

UIViewController *popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
popoverContent.view = v;


//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 216);

// dismiss existing popover
if (self.pcDatePicker)
{
    [self.pcDatePicker dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    self.pcDatePicker = nil;
}

//create a popover controller with my DatePickerViewController in it
UIPopoverController *popoverControllerForDate = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

//Set the delegate to self to receive the data of the Datepicker in the popover
popoverControllerForDate.delegate = self;

//Adjust the popover Frame to appear where I want
CGRect myFrame = sender.frame;//CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 320,     200);
myFrame.origin.x = 260;
myFrame.origin.y = 320;

//Present the popover
[popoverControllerForDate presentPopoverFromRect:myFrame
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];

self.pcDatePicker = popoverControllerForDate;
```

And then use the delegate Method to get the date:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    self.startDate = self.datePicker.date;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer if you want to do it by code, but the problem was how  to do it if you are using Storyboards.