# uidatepicker in uipopover delegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uidatepicker, uipopover

I am trying to insert a uipopover with uidatepicker in it with two buttons - Cancel and Done. I was able to design the layout using storyboard with the help of [UIDatePicker in UIPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover) and 
[How can I show a UIDatePicker inside a Popover on iPad using StoryBoard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993096/how-can-i-show-a-uidatepicker-inside-a-popover-on-ipad-using-storyboard)

But, I am not able to get the date from uidatepicker to uiviewcontroller when Done button is pressed. I am new to ios programming and i find delegate methods very confusing. Could somebody shed some light?
Help much appreciated. Thank you :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct one way to get the value in view controller is to implement delegate functions. These are very easy if you understand at the technical level. I will try to explain it here.

you have to define the protocol in the datePickerViewcontrollerClass.h like this

> ```
> @protocol TimePopupViewControllerDelegate <NSObject> 
> -(void)returnSelectedDate:(NSDate*)date;
> @end
> ```

and create a instance of 'id' type for passing the reference of mainViewController like this.

> @property (nonatomic, assign) id < TimePopupViewControllerDelegate > delegate;

in MainViewController.m where you are creating instance of datePickerViewcontrollerClass, you have to set the delegate like this

> ```
> datePickerViewcontrollerClass *myViewControllerForPopover =[[datePickerViewcontrollerClass alloc] init];
> myViewControllerForPopover.delegate = self;
> ```

in the method where you getting the date from picker in datePickerViewcontrollerClass.m class you have to pass it to main class using delegate.

> ```
> -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
>      [_delegate returnSelectedDate:datepicker.date];
> [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
> ```
>
> }

you can write this in any method I have written in ViewWillDisappear or any other method.

After this in MainViewController this method get called and you can retrieve the selected date

> ```
> -(void)returnSelectedDate:(NSDate *)date{
> }
> ```

Technically you are passing the referece of mainViewController instance to your datePickerViewcontrollerClass and calling the methods on mainViewController from datePickerViewcontrollerClass
I hope I will be able to explain it clearly if you still any doubt you can comment.

Comment: Thanks @Parser, for the very detailed explaination. I have done like you said except that I called the delegate method inside donebutton press..the delegate doesnt seem to be working..also how can I dismiss the popover on the click of done/cancel button?

Comment: Also, DO I need to perform any segues??

Answer (score 1):

In UIPopover, you must be loading one viewcontroller which contains that datepicker.

So in that viewcontroller, write IBAction methods for Done and Cancel buttons.

**Done** button:

- We can achieve this using Protocol -

> DatePickerContainerVC.delegate = myViewController

- Requires to declare a method in Protocol `-(void)selectedDate: (NSDate *)aDate` and implement this method in *myViewController*
- Call a delegate method from DateContainerVC - `[self.delegate selectedDate:datePicker.date];`
- This will call your view controller method where you can change your label or button text with date parameter.

**Cancel** button:

- Call delegate method same as above `-(void)cancelDatePickerPopover;`
- Here dismiss your popover controller

Comment: Can you be more detail..inside the action method of done button, I am calling the delegate method, it doesnt seem to be working :( '- (IBAction)doneButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"donebuttonpress");
     [self.delegate receiveDate:pickedDate];
}'