# uipopover with uidatepicker delegate not working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uipickerview, uipopover

I have created a popover with datepicker in storyboard which pops when a button is pressed. After a date is selected and done button is pressed, the date has to be sent to the `UIViewController`.

I have set up protocols and delegate methods as explained by [uidatepicker in uipopover delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628104/uidatepicker-in-uipopover-delegate) but the delegate method in my viewcontroller is never called up. Am I missing something? Do I need to use segues for this?? Please help!!

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"donebuttonpress");
    [_delegate receiveDate:pickedDate];
    NSLog(@"afterdelegation");
}
```

Both the `donebuttonpress` and `afterdelegation` are printed, but the method has never been called :(

//selectDatePopover.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol selectDatePopoverDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)receiveDate:(NSString *)theDate;
@end

@interface selectDatePopover : UIViewController{
    id <selectDatePopoverDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id < selectDatePopoverDelegate > delegate;
- (IBAction)doneButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)mydatepicker:(UIDatePicker *)sender;
@end
```

//selectDatePopover.m

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"donebuttonpress");
    NSLog(_delegate);
    [_delegate receiveDate:pickedDate];
    NSLog(@"afterdelegation");
}

- (IBAction)mydatepicker:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    pickedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
    NSLog(pickedDate);
}
```

//CheckIn_ViewController.h

```
#import "selectDatePopover.h"
@interface CheckIn_ViewController : UIViewController <selectDatePopoverDelegate>
    @property UIPopoverController *popover;
@end
```

//CheckIn_ViewController.m

```
- (void)receiveDate:(NSString *)theDate {
    NSLog(@"backhere");
    dateLabel.Text = theDate;
}
```

//On the press on this button, popover has to show up:

```
- (IBAction)calendarbutton:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIView *anchor = sender;
    selectDatePopover *selectDatePopoverInstance =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectDatePopover"];
    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:selectDatePopoverInstance];
    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                         inView:anchor.superview
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    selectDatePopoverInstance.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Try logging _delegate and also pickedDate to make sure that neither is nil.

Comment: pickedDate is not empty..I logged it..but dont know how to log delegate..??

Comment: Then post the code where you set the delegate, and also the .h file where you create the delegate protocol and the delegate property.

Comment: I just tried NSLog(delegate) and it returned empty @rdelmar

Comment: The log should be NSLog(@"%@",_delegate). Put it in the doneButtonPress method.

Comment: please check now..i have included my code @rdelmar

Comment: @rdelmar and it works like a charm..thanks a ton for all the patience :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: self.popover.delegate = self; is incorrect. The delegate protocol isn't in the popover class, it's in its content view controller, which is selectDatePopover. So, change that line to:

```
selectDatePopover.delegate = self;
```

Comment: it returns a error: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: You need to change the UIViewController in this line:" UIViewController *selectDatePopover = [self.storyboard ...." to selectDatePopover (that is your class name -- it would be better for that to be capitalized, but since you didn't, you might want to change the name of the instance so they're not the same).

Comment: the warning is gone..but I still cant get the delegate working :(

Comment: Please update you question to show the code you're trying now. What is not working now? Is _delegate still nil when you log it?

Comment: @KedariTheja, Is this a typo: initWithContentViewController:selectDatePopover. It should now be initWithContentViewController:selectDatePopoverInstance