# Storyboard ViewController freeform size not kept while presenting it

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've read a few questions about it without solving my problem.

I've got a `UIViewController` subclass as a `rootViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, the both are set with the same size of 320x1024 pts with the freeform simulated size. Their owned views have the same size and the checkbox `Resize View From Nib` is NOT selected.

The `UINavigationController` is presented using a custom segue, that makes the destination view controller slide in (an animation close to mail app).

If I log or debug the segue code I can see clearly (from the very beginning) that the view size isn't respected and this happens both in the `UINavigationController` and in its `rootViewController`, their size is full screen.

I know that I can fix the size inside the segue manually or with constraints, but I'm wondering if I am missing something to preserve the storyboard size.
The app should work only on ipad.

Comment: Simulated metrics ia just that.. simulated. It doesn't actually set the size of your views.

Comment: @Tander thank you, yep I was guessing the same, but it seems that someone managed successfully this operation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728952/resize-of-uiviewcontroller-in-storyboard , but for me doesn't work

Comment: Yes, but that was on an iPad (Since iPhone doesn't have popOverViews) and setting the size in Storyboard will probably work fine then. On iPhone - Apple expect all viewControllers to be full screen. Unless they are in containers.

Comment: Right... need to add a spec: I'm on ipad

Comment: Well then, that changes things. I'll take a look tonight and see if I can get it right and pop an answer if I do?

Comment: Thanks.. I think the main problem is that I'm embedding inside a NavController

Comment: A workaround for this is to use xib instead.