# Resize UIVIewController in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode6.1

I am working on the example from RayWanderLich

I am trying to implement slide panels similar to facebook. I have two panels: center and left and there is a container panel.

[image]

[image]

When user press the Kitties (top left button) on Center Panel. Left View Controller (i set width as 400 in storyboard, above image) should be slided over the top of Center Panel.

But when i build the app. i can see the Left view width with 400 px. But the Left View Controller fills the entire screen by hiding center panel.

In this image, i set the left view controller color as Green. It overlaps center view controller.

[image]

How can i resize the view controller. Or is there any other better way to implement.

**What i am trying to accompolish:**
There are two view controllers. one is center and other is left. when i click on a button in center view, the left view should be slide over on the top of center like in Split View controller.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so, you have to set the constraints properly.

Comment: yes. i am using AutoLayout. I have to resize View Controller width. It's default to 768(Portrait). How can i use constraint to View controller

Comment: ctrl-drag horizontally on the view, then choose "width". You should read a tutorial on autolayout (also available on Ray Wenderlich's site).

Comment: The View Controller (not View) should be resized to specified width. I can resize View but i want to resize View Controller

Comment: i added a new image of resizing view controller. Please check it

Comment: This Fix my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728952/resize-of-uiviewcontroller-in-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the View Controller in Storyboard. Select ViewController->Show Attributes Inspector -> Simulated metrics -> Size -> freeform

Comment: yes. i tried it. But it is not changing the view controller width.

Comment: are you pushing that view controller?

Comment: Why don't you use SplitViewController to make this easy?

Comment: No I am not pushing. i took the sample code from http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift