# Add space to storyboard scene

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using XCode with Storyboards to develop an iOS app. I've run out of space in one of my Scenes. Is there a way to add more space to the scene?

Comment: I mean the scene is out of space. So the particular UIView I'm adding components to has no more space to add components too, such as a UITextField.

Comment: do you use size class?

Comment: I don't use size classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728952/resize-of-uiviewcontroller-in-storyboard

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to iOS development. I am using size classes, but the width and height are currently set to 'Any'

Comment: That's fine, but if you need to change the size of a particular UIViewController, then you can do that by selecting the scene and changing the properties on Attributes Inspector

Comment: The size and width boxes are grayed out.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cuSTl.png you have to make sure you make the vc as freeform based on the image

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should use scroll view: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your view controller as freeform as found in this image
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuSTl.png

This will allow you to change your width and height.