# Run out of space on Xcode Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I have been developing an app on the storyboard, but have come across the issue of needing to add more views to the screen, but having no space to put them anywhere on the Storyboard.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234312/add-space-to-storyboard-scene) answer on Stack Overflow which seems to answer my question, but it has left me with a blue area in the newly created space. If I drag all of my views down into the new space (to create a gap for some new views at the top), they just get hidden behind the bluefish area.

If it helps - I have a Scroll View first, then a view on top, and then all of my individual views on top of that.

[Storyboard before expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z569I.png)

[Storyboard after expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cshN.png)

Comment: Use [Refactor to Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/RefactorStoryboard.html) option to create sub storyboards.

Comment: Do you have too many controllers or do you have not enough space inside one controller?

Comment: The latter (kind of) - not necessarily that I have too much, but that I don't have enough space to add more. As you can see from my first image, I have a few sliders and a view to hold a graph (represented by the big gap). I want to be able to shift all of it down to add some more text at the top of the screen. Everything is embedded in a UIScrollView so it can vertically scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use not one storyboard, but for example you can create new storyboard for any related area. That will give you good logic splitting, remove lags in huge storyboards, make build time lower etc... It has a lot of benefits.

Comment: Okay, but how would this give me more space on that particular screen? I want to be able to add more Views to that controller.

Comment: Mb I understood not correctly, is the problem that some elements is out of screen and you can receive them, or problem is that you can add new screen(controller) to storyboard file, because it's overloaded. 
If problem is second, than you will refactor storyboard and split it to multiple storyboards, that will cause reducing amount of controllers in your current storyboard and some space will be freed . If problem is first, than it won't help and I just misunderstood you.