# Is there a way to visualise the navigation structure of a SwiftUI app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to overview the navigation of a SwiftUI app like it was with Storyboard in the UIKit "era" with arrows connecting different Views?

Upd 1. So if it’s not possible atm, how do you handle that? Just keep some hand drawing in sync with the actual structure?

Comment: No, there are no GUI tools for visualizing the UI like that.

Comment: It’s super convenient imo, especially, for introducing the project to someone new.

Comment: The issue is that the views can be created on the fly. With UIKit, everything was set except for the data going in by StoryBoard. The best you can do is a mock up.

Comment: I understand that SwiftUI is dynamic. One could speculate on parsing all the navigation links, tabs etc to draw at least *some* structure, even if it’s not going to be a ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (hacky) workaround:

- Put code that [takes a screenshot of the view](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image) and [saves it to a location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837120/3151675) to the views' onAppear.
- [Download the images from the container.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176332/3151675)
- Open the container (right click, Show Package Contents).
- Navigate to the folder you've saved the images to (print out the folder structure in your code to make it easier).
- Drag the images to your xcassets file.
- Make the structure yourself in a storyboard.
- [Resize the UIViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166365/3151675) to the size of the UIHostingController in the first step.
- Create UIImageViews and resize them to the correct size.
- Select the correct image for each of them.